# Docker Nginx proxy - CORS error for POST requests in Angular App

Tags: asp.net, angular, docker, nginx

I am running into something that is extremely odd. I have the following stack:

- ASP.Net Core 3.1 API
- Angular 10 front end app
- Nginx proxy

All of the applications are containerized so I have my API running in a docker container, my angular app in a docker container (that is also using a separate nginx web server to serve the SPA), and a nginx container serving as a proxy for the API.

Below is a typical GET request that has no issues and the relevant headers for the OPTIONS request:
[image]

[image]

So a GET request is working but when I try to use POST, the options request succeeds immediately followed by a 400 from nginx along with an error message from the browser:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://restaurantapi.localhost/chats. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

**The odd part about above error message is that the OPTIONS request for the POST succeeds:**
[image]

[image]

How is it possible for the OPTIONS request to be successfully returned but the POST fails? I don't understand quite how this is possible. I know its Nginx causing this issue because I have removed the proxy and sent the request directly from my angular app in a container to the API using kestrel web server (built in webserver for .NET core) and it succeeds.

Is there any configuration I am missing causing this problem? Note that I am adding the CORS headers within my API and am not using CORS through nginx. I also tried stripping response headers from API within Nginx and explicitly adding CORS headers and that still fails. Any help on this would be appreciated.

My nginx config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    underscores_in_headers on;

    upstream api {
        server restaurantapi:5001;
    }
    upstream grpcservice {
        server restaurantapi:5010;
    }

    # redirect all http requests to https
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        server_name restaurantapi.localhost;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/certs/resapi.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/resapi.key;
    
        location /CartCheckoutService/ValidateCartCheckout {
            grpc_pass grpc://grpcservice;
            error_page 502 = /error502grpc;
        }
    
        location = /error502grpc {
            internal;
            default_type application/grpc;
            add_header grpc-status 14;
            add_header grpc-message "Error connecting to gRPC service.";
            return 204;
        }
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;           
        }
    }
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/xml;
}
```

The logs from the API:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was websocket headers being present (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html). I'm not entirely sure nginx does not log a connection error to the upstream server because all the logs displayed was the request to nginx.

Removing the websocket specific headers fixed the issue I was having. I need to add the headers only for websocket requests.